# mongoengine: test1 is not a valid ObjectId

Tags: python, pymongo, mongoengine

I got the following error message:

```
$ python tmp2.py
why??
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp2.py", line 15, in <module>
test._id = ObjectId(i[0])
  File "/home/mictadlo/.virtualenvs/unisnp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bson/objectid.py", line 92, in __init__
self.__validate(oid)
  File "/home/mictadlo/.virtualenvs/unisnp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bson/objectid.py", line 199, in __validate
raise InvalidId("%s is not a valid ObjectId" % oid)
bson.errors.InvalidId: test1 is not a valid ObjectId
```

with this code:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from mongoengine import *


class Test(Document):
    _id = ObjectIdField(required=True)
    tag = StringField(required=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
connect('dbtest2')
print "why??"
for i in [('test1', "a"), ('test2', "b"), ('test3', "c")]:
    test = Test()
    test._id = ObjectId(i[0])
    test.char = i[1]
    test.save()
```

How is it possible to use its own ids which are unique too?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation: http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#fields, ObjectIdField  is 'A field wrapper around MongoDB’s ObjectIds.'. So it cannot accept a string `test1` as an object id.

You may have to change the code to something like this:

```
 for i in [(bson.objectid.ObjectId('test1'), "a"), (bson.objectid.ObjectId('test2'), "b"), (bson.objectid.ObjectId('test3'), "c")]:
```

for your code to work (Assuming `test1` etc are valid id)

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error with your code example.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

`ObjectId` receives a 24 hex string, you can't initialize it with that string. For instance, instead of using `'test1'` you can use a string such as `'53f6b9bac96be76a920e0799'` or `'111111111111111111111111'`. You don't even need to initialize an `ObjectId`, you could do something like this:

```
...
test._id = '53f6b9bac96be76a920e0799'
test.save()
...
```

I don't know what are you trying to accomplish by using `_id`. If you are trying to produce and id field or "primary key" for you document, it's not necessary because one is generated automatically. Your code would be:

```
class Test(Document):
    tag = StringField(required=True)

for i in [("a"), ("b"), ("c")]:
    test = Test()
    test.char = i[0]
    test.save()

print(test.id)  # would print something similar to 53f6b9bac96be76a920e0799
```

If you insist in using a field named `_id` you must know that your `id` will be the same, because internally, MongoDB calls it `_id`. If you still want to use `string1` as identifier you should do:

```
class Test(Document):
    _id = StringField(primary_key=True)
    tag = StringField(required=True)
```